# Intent extras on Service-Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I've got an Activity and a Service. In the service, I create a notification and if it is tapped, it opens the activity.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString(MainActivity.SELECTED_FRAGMENT,"GameFragment");
        extras.putParcelable(GameFragment.GAME_ARG,route);
        notificationIntent.putExtras(extras);
        Log.d("JON notification intent","Elements: " + notificationIntent.getExtras().size());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification =
                new Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText(getText(R.string.app_name))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_orbel_jokuek)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setTicker(getText(R.string.app_name))
                        .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
```

The problem is that on the method onCreate of the Activity:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        Log.d("JON intent size","Elements: " + getIntent().getExtras().size());
    }
```

I only get 1 extra, but I'm putting two extras on the notification intent. Any help or sense??

Thanks

Comment: i see a problem in your code

Comment: Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was using PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT on PendingIntent.getActivity() function.

Comment: please accept this answer to remove the question from the list of unanswered questions.